# utf-8 character in user path prevents module from being imported

Tags: python, python-2.7, nltk, python-import

The following error message is shown as I try to import `nltk` module

I actually have the `0xb3` (`ł`) character in my username, but what bothers me is that other modules like `re`, `codecs`, etc. are imported successfully.

Is it possible to solve it on Python side (without changing my username system-wide)?

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 310, in expanduser
    return userhome + path[i:]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Have you tried `userhome.decode('utf-8')` ?

Comment: After update to `ntpath.py` as you suggested it now complains the following: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 13: invalid start byte`

Answer (score 1):

As in the  `ntpath.py` file there is not an encoding for unicode username , you need to add the following command in `expanduser(path)` function in `ntpath.py` :

```
if isinstance(path, unicode):
    userhome = unicode(userhome,'unicode-escape').encode('utf8')
```

so `expanduser` function must be like the following :

```
def expanduser(path):
    """Expand ~ and ~user constructs.

    If user or $HOME is unknown, do nothing."""
    if isinstance(path, bytes):
        tilde = b'~'
    else:
        tilde = '~'
    if not path.startswith(tilde):
        return path
    i, n = 1, len(path)
    while i < n and path[i] not in _get_bothseps(path):
        i += 1

    if 'HOME' in os.environ:
        userhome = os.environ['HOME']
    elif 'USERPROFILE' in os.environ:
        userhome = os.environ['USERPROFILE']
    elif not 'HOMEPATH' in os.environ:
        return path
    else:
        try:
            drive = os.environ['HOMEDRIVE']
        except KeyError:
            drive = ''
        userhome = join(drive, os.environ['HOMEPATH'])

    if isinstance(path, bytes):
        userhome = userhome.encode(sys.getfilesystemencoding())

    if isinstance(path, unicode):
        userhome = unicode(userhome,'unicode-escape').encode('utf8')

    if i != 1: #~user
        userhome = join(dirname(userhome), path[1:i])

    return userhome + path[i:]
```

Comment: With this addition (instead of the one proposed by Bhargav Rao) I'm back to the original error:
`File "C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 311, in expanduser
    userhome = userhome.encode('utf8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 13: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: @pkrysiak what about the edit ? you can use `unicode()` fuction

Comment: I keep getting the same error. Just a side-note, I had to change `_get_bothseps(path)` to `"\\/"` because it was not recognized. Anyway, it keeps crashing on the same line as before.

Comment: `LookupError: unknown encoding: unicodeescape` this time. Can it be the difference between Python 2.7 and 3.4? I'm using the former one (added to tags)

Comment: "We need to go deeper". `UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape` is what it is now.